# Tkinter import and from

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a script that uses tkinter and this is how I start:

```
    import tkinter.messagebox
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
    from tkinter import ttk
```

I am mixing here both import and from..import. Is it ok? Is there another way so I do not mix them both?

Thanks

Comment: Each import statement works independently, so mixing styles is okay.  Stdlib modules mix 'import', 'from', and 'as' as appropriate, but avoid '*'.

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid then:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most of the import statements aee ok, but you should change `from tkinter import *` to `import tkinter` or `import tkinter as tk`. PEP8 suggests that global imports should be avoided, and that is good advice.

Comment: I personally use either 'import tkinter as tk' or specific imports such as 'from tkinter import Tk, Text'.  In any case, 'import *' disables certain code checks done by code checker programs.  You might someday want to use one.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: is that comment directed to me, or the OP?